# Indexing all columns which are foreign key to a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

```
                              Table "public.policy"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 pol_id | bigint  |           | not null | nextval('policy_pol_id_seq'::regclass)
 top_id | integer |           |          |
 idn_id | integer |           |          |
 rsc_id | integer |           |          |
 act_id | integer |           |          |
 tup_id | integer |           |          |
```

My table structure is this and all the columns other than pol_id are foreign keys. Searching for policy can happen on any of the column but it will be with top_id. eg; search for policies having top_id =1 and act_id =2.
How can I index this table better? Is it ok to just index top_id or is it ok to index all the columns.
This is a transaction table. Records in this table can be around a Million to 2 Maximum.

Comment: `nextval('policy_pol_id_seq'::regclass)` only looks to be compatible with Oracle and PostgreSQL database so iam removing the MySQL tag.. Only tag the database you are using.

Comment: The queries always or mostly use an equal operation on `top_id` and one other column except `pol_id`?

Comment: 1. select * from policy where top_id =1 and idn_id = 2 or  2. select * from policy where top_id =1 and act_id = 2; so on... or select * from policy where top_id =1. Any combination with top_id

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests four indexes:

- `top_id, idn_id`
- `top_id, rsc_id` or `rcs_id, top_id`
- `top_id, act_id` or `act_id, top_id`
- `top_id, tup_id` or `tup_id, top_id`

This is regardless of the database.  Oracle implements something called a "skip-scan" on the indexes.  This would allow you to reduce the number of indexes.

Whether these indexes are actually needed really depends on how selective `top_id` is.  If there are only a handful of matches, then an additional index per second key may not be necessary.

Comment: out of a million total records, each top_id will have 10K max records

Comment: @ShashankVC . . . That is a fair amount if you want really fast performance for all these queries.  On the other hand, four indexes add overhead to data modification operations.

Comment: So you are saying its better add 5 indexes or index on top_id would be sufficient?

Comment: @ShashankVC . . . It depends on how the table is being used and your performance requirements for updates.  Try the four indexes and see if they meet your needs.